# Limit playa total returned entries in control panel

Tags: channel-entries, playa, field-editor, memory-limit

We have about 7 playa fields in our entry form.

I want to limit the displaying entries but when searching, still to be available to get the desired one.

I believe that by limiting the number of shown entries, it will improve the loading time when editing a page like this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a dropdown menu on Playa's specific **Add/Edit Channel Field** ( Admin > Channel Fields > Group > Field ) form called **Limit entries to** - this is where you can set a limit.

Any searches/filters on the playa field will search/filter the all entires ( configured in the CP ) and not just filtered set.